# Subversion update

Tags: centos, unix, svn, centos5

I have a Subversion system running. It always does an post-commit update on `/var/www` by the following code:
`/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/`. But, this is OK when I am working on an other server. I do a commit, and it updates the `/var/www/` directory on the main server. But, when I am working on the main server, the post-commit hook will fail, because I am modifying files in `/var/www/`. How can I prevent this?

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12393283/462370

Comment: Simple, don't make modifications  on your production system.  That is a very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, I know... Can you please tell my boss :p..?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand well,
bu it looks like you are doing this on same server (srv1)
It fails when you add same hook while on a different server (srv2).

If you have same hook on srv2 and want update to update srv 1 you 
can use ssh command to execute cnv update remotely

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /usr/bin/svn update /var/www/
```

but for this to work without asking for password you need to setup keys for a user
that can run svn (avoid root)